# sound-How to customize the volume indication sound in ubuntu 16.0.4

Tags: sound, themes, indicator

When we increase or decrease the system output volume, it plays a "pop" sound that indicates the current volume. I am trying to use my own sound file instead of the default "pop". Is there a way of doing it? Just giving me the path to that file is enough. I have done a bit of moddng with ubuntu so I know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

System sounds are usually in:

```
/usr/share/sounds
```

The pop to indicate the current volume should be this one:

```
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-volume-change.oga
```